# script that checks for a file's existence in multiple directories, creates if not there (with 644 perms) else only chmods to 644

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a script that checks for a file's existence then if it is not existing it creates it with permissions of 644. if the file exists already it just makes sure permissions are 644. the script below works file for the present dir.

Point is I have probably 10 directories that I need to check and and perform the same thing.

example

```
/usr/local/opt/**app1**/logs/test`date '+%Y%m%d'`.log
```

app1 can be between 5 and 10 different applications.  The name is unique(it is not app1, app2 etc). the rest of the file dir structure is uniform/standard.

I can figure it out on the present dir with something like that:

```
if [ -f test`date '+%Y%m%d'`.log ];
then
    chmod 644 test`date '+%Y%m%d'`.log
    echo "File test`date '+%Y%m%d'`.log  exists and now it is readable by all"
else
    echo "File test`date '+%Y%m%d'`.log  does not exists creating"
    touch test`date '+%Y%m%d'`.log
    chmod 644 test`date '+%Y%m%d'`.log
fi
```

but I am stumped when there is the multiple dir element. 
putting the explicit dir structure is not a good idea as sometimes there are a number of  "apps" and some times a different number of apps. 
if the file exists I only want to chmod not touch as it already have data in it that should not be deleted.

Much appreciated any input.

Thanks

Nick

Comment: *not touch as it already have data in it that should not be deleted* : what makes you think that touch deletes any data? If the file already exists it just updates a date/time stamp.

Comment: point taken.  Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

```
for app in /usr/local/opt/*/*; do
    log_file=$app/logs/test$(date +%Y%m%d).log

    touch "$log_file"
    chmod 644 "$log_file"
done
```

Note that touching a file already exists doesn't delete its data. It's perfectly safe to touch files that already exist. It just updates their modification time, that's all.

Comment: this seems to do the trick. thank you so much sir. Where it says app{1..10}  I replaced  with a * since the naming convention is not standard/common.  Still testing.

Comment: ok another change I noticed that between the application dir and log dir there is a version. Again the version is different for each application. So effectively there are 2 wild cards. do I need to create a second parameter somewhow?  the directory structure is /usr/local/opt/**appl*/**version**/logs  (where application and version are not standard)

Answer (score 0):

I dont wanna write all the code out, but i would use `find /usr/local/opt -type d` then pipe that into `grep "/logs/"` then loop through the result directories looking for your test log files.